# How to determine if a List is sorted in Java?

Tags: java, generics, sorting, wildcard

I would like a method that takes a `List<T>` where `T` implements `Comparable` and returns `true` or `false` depending on whether the list is sorted or not.

What is the best way to implement this in Java?  It's obvious that generics and wildcards are meant to be able to handle such things easily, but I'm getting all tangled up.

It would also be nice to have an analogous method to check if the list is in reverse order.

Comment: Any chance you can use a sorted collection instead? Or just call .Sort() as needed instead?

Comment: The purpose of this is for testing, so no.

Comment: is the list supposed to be in ascending or descending order?

Comment: I'd like to be able to check both, as both types will occur.

Comment: generics have nothing to do with sorting or comparability, they have to do with Type safety and that is all.

Comment: @fuzzy lollipop -- I was hoping to implement this method in type-safe way.

Answer (score 136, accepted):

[Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) provides this functionality through its [Comparators](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/22.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Comparators.html#isInOrder-java.lang.Iterable-java.util.Comparator-) class.

```
boolean sorted = Comparators.isInOrder(list, comparator);
```

---

There's also the [Ordering](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html) class, though this is mostly obsolete. An `Ordering` is a `Comparator`++. In this case, if you have a list of some type that implements `Comparable`, you could write:

```
boolean sorted = Ordering.natural().isOrdered(list);
```

This works for any `Iterable`, not just `List`, and you can handle `null`s easily by specifying whether they should come before or after any other non-`null` elements:

```
Ordering.natural().nullsLast().isOrdered(list);
```

Also, since you mentioned that you'd like to be able to check for reverse order as well as normal, that would be done as:

```
Ordering.natural().reverse().isOrdered(list);
```

Comment: And there is also `isStrictlyOrdered()` if you want to make sure there are no duplicates.

Comment: +1 for pointing to existing code so that people stop reinventing things and start making new things.

Comment: Can you show an example of this if there is no natural ordering and you want to pass in a `Comparator`?  I think that's what `Ordering.from` is for: "Returns an ordering based on an existing comparator instance. Note that it is unnecessary to create a new anonymous inner class implementing Comparator just to pass it in here. Instead, simply subclass Ordering and implement its compare method directly."

Comment: @tieTYT: You can using `Ordering.from(comparator).isOrdered(list)`; if you're implementing the comparator yourself, though, you might as well just extend `Ordering` rather than implementing `Comparator` to begin with, in which case it's just `myOrdering.isOrdered(list)`.

Comment: Following the suggestion to use Ordering.from(comparator).isOrdered(list):
Using a Java 8 lambda expression in order to implement the comparator parameter of the from method can be a useful and elegant solution for customized ordering.

Comment: Just leaving a note here. Most of ordering is Obsolete but they removed the comments for planned deletion here.
https://github.com/google/guava/commit/3a053c298ce800315a92365fbc8f62a08babc09d?diff=split

Answer (score 42):

## Stream

If you are using [Java 8](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_8) or later, [streams](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html) may be able to help.

```
list.stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList()).equals(list);
```

More briefly, in [Java 16](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_16)+, using [`Stream#toList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toList()).

```
list.stream().sorted().toList().equals(list);
```

This code will sort the list out of place and collect its elements in another list, which is then compared to the initial list. The comparison will be successful, if both lists contain the same elements in equal positions.

Note that this method will have worse space and time complexity than other approaches because it will have to sort the list out of place, so it should not be used for very large lists. But it is the easiest to use because it is a single expression and does not involve 3rd party libraries.

Comment: Nice ... obviously didn't help 2010 me using Java 6, but this is a good addition.

Comment: Much less effective than ideal allocation-less and sorting-less solution.

Comment: According to Java 8 docs, Collectors.toList(); There are no guarantees on the type, mutability, serializability, or thread-safety of the {@code List} returned; You should use a supplier of ArrayList

Comment: It does not look like this is relevant for this case, as the generated list never outlives is statement, so it will never be serialized, mutated or accessed from multiple threads.

Answer (score 29):

Here's a generic method that will do the trick:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>>
        boolean isSorted(Iterable<T> iterable) {
    Iterator<T> iter = iterable.iterator();
    if (!iter.hasNext()) {
        return true;
    }
    T t = iter.next();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        T t2 = iter.next();
        if (t.compareTo(t2) > 0) {
            return false;
        }
        t = t2;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 23):

Easy:

```
List tmp = new ArrayList(myList);
Collections.sort(tmp);
boolean sorted = tmp.equals(myList);
```

Or (if elements are comparable):

```
Object prev = null;
for( Object elem : myList ) {
    if( prev != null && prev.compareTo(elem) > 0 ) {
        return false;
    }
    prev = elem;
}
return true;
```

Or (if elements are not comparable):

```
Object prev = null;
for( Object elem : myList ) {
    if( prev != null && myComparator.compare(prev,elem) > 0 ) {
        return false;
    }
    prev = elem;
}
return true;
```

The implementations fail for lists containing null values. You have to add appropriate checks in this case.

Comment: Collections.sort would require that the list elements be comparable already, and that was a stipulation in the question in any event.

Comment: I think your first example is missing a line, since `tmp` is not populated.

Comment: The first example is also pretty wasteful for what it does, and the Objects in the second need to be Comparable.

Comment: @Daniel Does prev need to be initialized?

Comment: @MosesKirathe: Yes

Answer (score 10):

If you need it for unit testing, you can use [AssertJ](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/). It contains an assertion to check if a List is sorted:

```
List<String> someStrings = ...
assertThat(someStrings).isSorted();
```

There is also an alternative method `isSortedAccordingTo` that takes a comparator in case you want to use a custom comparator for the sorting.

Answer (score 5):

To check whether a list or any data structure for that matter is a task that only takes O(n) time. Just iterate over the list using the `Iterator` Interface and run through the data (in your case you already have it ready as a type of Comparable) from start to end and you can find whether its sorted or not easily

Comment: Interestingly, your algorithm is actually O(1) expected time for reasonably random lists.

Comment: It would be O(n) in the worst case (when the list is indeed sorted).

Comment: -1 since the asker has indicated he's getting "tangled up" in implementation issues like generics and wildcards, I think this answer is only telling him things he already knows.

Answer (score 5):

```
private static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> boolean isSorted(List<T> array){
    for (int i = 0; i < array.size()-1; i++) {
        if(array.get(i).compareTo(array.get(i+1))> 0){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

zzzzz not sure guys what you guys are doing but this can be done in simple for loop.

Comment: fwiw, the implementation of the library in the accepted answer (Guava) is essentially this: https://github.com/google/guava/blob/e7700e6f78d9594d1ee37d43bf4e0aa1e58b4e7a/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.java#L895

But IMO it's always better to keep your codebase small rather than reimplementing things a library can give you.

Comment: This is so much better than sorting the array and checking if they are equal.

Answer (score 4):

Simply use the iterator to look through the contents of the `List<T>`.

```
public static <T extends Comparable> boolean isSorted(List<T> listOfT) {
    T previous = null;
    for (T t: listOfT) {
        if (previous != null && t.compareTo(previous) < 0) return false;
        previous = t;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: This keeps continuing because `previous` will never be set. See answer of Daniel for right flow.

Comment: Would need to be constrained to `<T extends Comparable>` as well of course.

Comment: @Colin (and everyone else) I am sorry that this doesn't compile.  I wrote it very quickly. Colin, you have edit power, feel free to fix this error I made.

Comment: I've accepted the solution that avoids using raw types.  This was my second choice, though, so I've upvoted it.

Comment: @FarmBoy, Thanks for the feed back! Glad we could help.

Answer (score 2):

Using Java 8 streams:

```
boolean isSorted = IntStream.range(1, list.size())
        .map(index -> list.get(index - 1).compareTo(list.get(index)))
        .allMatch(order -> order <= 0);
```

This also works for empty lists. It is however only efficient for lists that also implement the `RandomAccess` marker interface (e.g., `ArrayList`).

If you do not have access to the stream's underlying collection, the following ugly hack can be used:

```
Stream<T> stream = ...
Comparator<? super T> comparator = ...
boolean isSorted = new AtomicInteger(0) {{
    stream.sequential()
          .reduce((left, right) -> {
               getAndUpdate(order -> (order <= 0) ? comparator.compare(left, right) : order);
               return right;
          });
}}.get() <= 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an operation that will take O(n) time (worst case). You will need to handle two cases: where the list is sorted in descending order, and where the list is sorted in ascending order.

You will need to compare each element with the next element while making sure that the order is preserved.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I would do:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> boolean isSorted(List<T> list) {
    if (list.size() != 0) {
        ListIterator<T> it = list.listIterator();
        for (T item = it.next(); it.hasNext(); item = it.next()) {
            if (it.hasPrevious() && it.previous().compareTo(it.next()) > 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }

    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1,2,9,7,4);
        System.out.println(isSorted(list));
    }
```

expecte print false, but print true.

Answer (score 0):

One simple implementation on arrays:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> boolean isSorted(T[] a, int start, int end) {
    while (start<end) {
        if (a[start].compareTo(a[start+1])>0) return false;
        start++;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Converting for lists:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> boolean isSorted(List<T> a) {
    int length=a.size();
    if (length<=1) return true;

    int i=1;
    T previous=a.get(0);
    while (i<length) {
        T current=a.get(i++);
        if (previous.compareTo(current)>0) return false;
        previous=current;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: p.s. note the implementation is deliberately designed to avoid allocating an iterator or making multiple calls to get. This is designed for the common case where you are using an ArrayList, for other list implementation you are probably better off using the iterator.

Comment: One thing that could be done in this case would be to check if the `List` implements `RandomAccess` and use this implementation if so and an `Iterator` implementation if not. You wouldn't really want to use this with a `LinkedList` as is.

Comment: @ColinD great idea! I'm guessing you could do this so that it detects this at compile as well

Answer (score 0):

Here comes a method using an `Iterable` and a `Comparator`.

```
<T> boolean isSorted(Iterable<? extends T> iterable,
                     Comparator<? super T> comparator) {
    boolean beforeFirst = true;
    T previous = null;
    for (final T current : iterable) {
        if (beforeFirst) {
            beforeFirst = false;
            previous = current;
            continue;
        }
        if (comparator.compare(previous, current) > 0) {
            return false;
        }
        previous = current;
    }
    return true;
}
```

And a method for an `Iterable` of `Comparable` and a flag for ordering.

```
<T extends Comparable<? super T>> boolean isSorted(
        Iterable<? extends T> iterable, boolean natural) {
    return isSorted(iterable, natural ? naturalOrder() : reverseOrder());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IMO, from what I'm seeing, the complexity of checking this is as bad as performing the sort for a second time, and I understand people are short circuiting with returns if it is not sorted, but if the List is actually sorted, then the entire length will be traversed..., I'd argue to just let the code continue as if the List was sorted, and let the code itself figure out if it is or not.

I would recommend placing an Error detailing why the specific line that will fail is doing so because its collection is not reversed/ordered etc...

eg.

the line `detachTailIndex.run()` will give a NullPointerException(),

```
if (fromReversedMethod && detachTailIndex == null) {
throw new NullPointerException("detachTailIndex was null. \n 
Reason: The List<> is required to be reversed before submission")
}
```

Or if your plan is to use a conditional for when sorted or not the you can use the null to verify if it is sorted and choose the other option.

**If there is no other option, then using the other responses are ok.**

Here is another example:

```
    int key = entry.getKey();
    
    List<Integer> shouldBeReversed = entry.getValue();

    try {
        //If all entries need to be iterated better place them inside the Try-Catch
            updateBatch(key,
                    xes -> {
                        for (int rowIndex : shouldBeReversed
                        ) {
                            xes.remove((int) rowIndex); // will return an IndexOutOfBoundsException if not sorted in reverse
                        }
                        return xes;
                    }
            );
    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(e.getMessage() + "\n" +
                "Reason: Batch indexes (Entry's value \"List<Integer>\") should be sorted in reverse order before submission");
    }
```

if conditional is required (on sorted, or on not sorted) then the
`catch()` body could be used as a "not sorted" option.

Of course this is very very case specific, but seems that checking for a sorting order just to get a boolean seems too much (?) specially on iterations.