# How to assert position of element on the list (Confirm it is first element on the list)

Tags: java, selenium, sorting, listview

I am fairly new at this. I am trying assert that elements are positioned in descending order and first one is latest dated one(2019,2018,2017,2016 etc)

here are the elements with DATES:

}-->2017/2018

}-->2016/2017

}-->2015/2016

}-->2014/2015

Comment: Can you elaborate more about your question? What do you want to get? Do you want to sort a list?

Answer (score -1):

Solution using `com.google.common.collect` is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047051/how-to-determine-if-a-list-is-sorted-in-java):

```
boolean isSorted = Ordering.natural().reverse().isOrdered(actualDates);
Assert.assertTrue(isSorted);
```

You can use `sort` and assert using TestNG:

```
// Assume it's your actual dates to check
List<String> actualDates = new ArrayList<>();
actualDates.add("2014/2015");
actualDates.add("2016/2017");
actualDates.add("2017/2018");
actualDates.add("2015/2016");

// Create new list,  add all from actual list and order it. 
List<String> sortedDates = new ArrayList<>(actualDates);
sortedDates.sort(Comparator.reverseOrder());

Assert.assertEquals(actualDates, sortedDates);
```

Comment: Where is OP's requirement to `assert` _that elements are positioned in descending order_ ?